# Does Ito isometry hold pointwise?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, isometry

It is known that the stochastic integral satisfies the following property

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left\langle \int_0^{\cdot}X(s)\,dM(s) \right\rangle_t\right]=
\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t X^2(s) \, d\left\langle M \right\rangle_s\right],
$$

where $M$ is a square integrable martingale, and $\langle\cdot \rangle$ denotes the quadratic variation which can be defined as
$$
\langle M \rangle_t=_{\mathbb{P}}\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{i\geq 0} \left(M\left(\frac{i+1}{2^n}\wedge t\right)-M\left(\frac{i}{2^n}\wedge t\right)\right)^2.
$$

I want to know if the above property holds ponit-wise a.s., i.e. whether

$$
\left\langle \int_0^\cdot X(s) \, dM(s) \right\rangle_t=
\int_0^t X^2(s) \, d\left\langle M \right\rangle_s,\text{ a.s.?}
$$

Comment: Yeah, it does...

Comment: Do you know a reference for a proof? Is it possible to prove without using a dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Do you consider cadlag martingales or martingales with continuous sample paths? (And why do you want to avoid the dominated convergence theorem?)